# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration')

Tags: reactjs

I Keep getting this error, I don't know what's wrong, all I want to do is to do is the code can read the detail, and store the duration, so that I can enter the voting room

here's the link to the code
https://github.com/fahmifakhir/voting-dapp/blob/main/VotingRoom.js

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193) or [links to GitHub](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Give more details. Leaving a link to check it for you is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 57 in your code:

`details` is not defined in the scope.

You can pass it as parameter or define this variable inside the `getStatus` function.